# The series $\sum\limits_ {k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1+kx)^2}$ converges for $x>0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$ \sum_ {k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{(1+kx)^2}$$  $$x\in (0,\infty) $$ 
This series converges on given interval but how exactly can I show this is true?

Comment: hint: factor out the $x$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$x>0\implies(1+kx)^2\ge k^2x^2\implies\frac1{(1+kx)^2}\le\frac1{k^2x^2}$$

and now use the comparison test.

Comment: And it become $\leq \frac{\pi^2}{6x^2}$.

Comment: @TakahiroWaki That's unimportant to reach the conclusion the series converges.

Comment: I consider,  It is important that this function converge to a value smaller than \frac{\pi^2}{6x^2}. Also that's clear.

Comment: @TakahiroWaki It is clear...if one **already** knows that $$\zeta(2)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}=\frac\pi6$$ a fact which isn't trivial and not so very well known in the beginning of real analysis.

Comment: If that is so, just you may tell this is $\pi^2/6$. If you so, I would rate your answer is perfect. I upvoted E.H.E's answer, too.

Answer (score 1):

### Hint:

$$\sum_ {k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{(1+kx)^2}<\sum_ {k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{(1+k^2x^2)}$$
we know that
$$\sum_ {k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{(1+k^2x^2)}=\frac{1}{2x}(x+\pi\coth\frac{\pi}{x})$$

Answer (score 0):

For any $x>0$, the function
$$ f_x(k)=\frac{1}{(1+kx)^2}$$
is a decreasing function on $\mathbb{R}^+$. It follows that
$$ \sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{1}{(1+kx)^2}=f_x(1)+f_x(2)+f_x(3)+\ldots \leq \int_{0}^{+\infty}f_x(k)\,dk = \frac{1}{x}.$$
The actual value of the series is
$$ \frac{1}{x^2}\cdot\psi'\!\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right) $$
where $\psi(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\log\Gamma(x)=\frac{\Gamma'(x)}{\Gamma(x)}$ (the $\Gamma$ function is holomorphic in the right half-plane).

Answer (score 0):

I wonder Why won't the ratio test be sufficient

$\displaystyle lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(n+1)th term}{nth term} = lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1 + 2kn + n^2*k^2}{1 + 2(k+1)n + (k+1)^2*n^2} = \frac{k^2}{(k+1)^2} <1 $. Hence the series absolutely converges.

Perhaps this could help you better: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests

Comment: In ratio test you must take a limit.  Fails.

Comment: The ratio test isn't concluyent here: the sup lim of the quotient must be a number *less* than one, not one.. Otherwise, your argument would give that the harmonic series $\;\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty\frac1{n-1}\;$ converges, since $$\frac{\frac1n}{\frac1{n-1}}=\frac{n-1}n<1$$ which is absurd.